# Regex to split string into verying size chunks

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to break a string into chunks of varying sizes, creating a "wave" of words such as:

```
          the
        cat sat
     on the mat the
  cat sat on the mat the
     cat sat on the
        mat the
          cat
```

As words have varying lengths I want to split on the nearest space.

I may be trying to do too much with one line. However I don't like the idea of loops. I've started with this:

```
/.{5}\w*/g
```

I've tried adding () around and adding {} but can't quite get the hang of regexes. Is this possible to do? Or will there involve some sort of loop?

Comment: What's wrong with loops?

Comment: As CoderDennis implied RegEx is not the answer to the problem.

Comment: The problem needs to be specified more precisely.  Do you know how many characters and/or words you want to appear on each line?

Comment: Guys, regex is an extremely powerful part of Javascript and I've been scared off them for a long time (sounds like some of you have too?) @phari, see answer below, strubizhev seemed to understand it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something that can be done even with a regex, BUT a lot depends on the input string. Also, you will have to think about how to arrange chunks, whether to trim or not, how to pad, etc. so just a regex won't do.

This regex pattern:
`((?:[^\s]+(?:\s|$)){1,20})`
can yield something similar to what you are looking for in the following string:
`the   cat sat   on the mat the    cat sat on the mat the      cat sat on the  mat`. It works because of additional spaces right where the breakdown should occur.

```
the 
cat sat 
on the mat the 
cat sat on the mat the 
cat sat on the 
mat
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lH8nB7/1).